# ls option to list a symlink reference only (no dates, permissions, size, etc.)

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

If I use:

```
$ ls -l mysymlinkname
```

I get:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ownr grp 46 Jan 19 17:15 mysymlinkname -> /home/ownr/path/target
```

All I want is:

```
/home/ownr/path/target
```

to put into a bash variable.

Is there an `ls` option for that? or a simple reliable `bash` command to extract it?

Comment: `readlink file-that-is-a-link` generally works, if you have readlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls -l `pwd`/mysymlinkname | awk '{print $NF}'
```

To put it into a variable:

```
VARIABLE=$(ls -l `pwd`/mysymlinkname | awk '{print $NF}')
```

Comment: Why/when is `\`pwd\`/` needed?

Comment: Ah, probably not needed, but it doesn't hurt. :)

Comment: It hurts in that it requires spawning a sub-shell and using the `pwd` builtin. As compared to `$PWD` which is a variable expansion. That being said it is also entirely pointless since for the current directory `.` works just as well (as does not including either of them at all).

Comment: @EtanReisner `-l` pointless? I don't think so. Without it, you only get the link name not the target path, which is what I want. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Harvey Ah, true. Sorry. That being said `readlink` as in the comment is a better answer.

Comment: @EtanReisner Very good! That makes things much simpler for me.